# Why are inherit fields not showing in Odoo 12?

Tags: inheritance, barcode, odoo-12

I am trying to inherit filed under new tab in sale module's product section. I try and code is working fine but it's just showing tab not showing filed under that tab. Let me share my code with you. Please help me to find where i am missing

Here is my module code

```
class ProductTemplate (models.Model): 
    _inherit = 'product.template' 
    field_name1 = fields.Char (string = "label for the field")
```

Here is my view code is

```
<record id = "product_template_sale" model = "ir.ui.view">
    <field name = "name"> product.tamplate.tab </field> 
    <field name = "model"> product.template </field> 
    < field name = "inherit_id" ref = "product.product_template_only_form_view" /> 
    <field name = "arch" type = "xml"> 
        <notebook> 
            <page string = "Barcode"> 
                 <filed name = "field_name1" /> 
            </ page> 
        </notebook> 
    </field> 
</record>
```

There is showing new tab Barcode which i want to develop but filed is not showing there. 
Why it's not showing and what i did wrong please help me to find it.

Comment: Check the <filed name = "field_name1" /> spelling is wrong
<field name = "field_name1"/>

Answer (score 2):

While creating new tab and inside that, if you want to add field in that tab then you have to include that field into the group.

Your .py file is up to date, but need to do small change in the .xml file

```
<record id = "product_template_sale" model = "ir.ui.view">
<field name = "name"> product.tamplate.tab </field> 
<field name = "model"> product.template </field> 
<field name = "inherit_id" ref = "product.product_template_only_form_view" /> 
<field name = "arch" type = "xml"> 
 <notebook>
    <page string="Barcode">
        <group name= "barcode_group">
            <field name="field_name1"/>
        </group>  
    </page>
 </notebook>
</field>
```